# SEO impact while using h1 text with inline SVG

Tags: seo, images, heading, svg

I have a site title, let's say "My site" inside an `h1` tag, where I would like to use an inline SVG instead of the letter `i`. Something like the following:

"My s`<svg ... />`te"

Googling hasn't helped me much. I would like to know if this would affect SEO negatively?

If so, how can I still provide Search engines the site name as "My Site" while still using the SVG?

Is there any option similar to `alt` attribute that we use for an image?

Answer (score -1):

My opinion is that it will not hurt it. SVG is an XML-based format that is well supported by Google, so I think it will be understood correctly.

Comment: You really think that Google would be able to see `s<svg ... />te` as the word `site`?  Unless the svg image just rendered the letter `i` as text, I don't even see how Google would be able to do that, and even in that case, I doubt that it would work.

Comment: You are hastily criticizing something you haven't tested. I recommend you to test and then judge.